# How to call Adminhtml Controller on form action in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom

I have created a custom module.
Which adds a custom tab on product_edit page.
Custom tab have multiple images and text boxes.
this all include in 1 custom form like this...

```
<form action="<?php echo $baseurl.'admin/AdminSample/sampleOne';?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and i want on Save button click the form should call controller in which i can handle all posted data.

I have tried call controller using basepath, but it always redirect me to admin dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling of admin url of `echo $baseurl.'admin/AdminSample/sampleOne'`; is not  wrong idea.

If you want call `admin url then you should try`

```
$this->getUrl('AdminSample/sampleOne')
```

at block class.

Comment: I got the inputs, but still i want the image details like name, size, type, tmp_name, etc.

Comment: i Got this much

Comment: Array
(
    [fileToUpload1] => 54874.png
    [fileToUpload2] => 88286.png
    [fileToUpload3] => facebook.png
    [fileToUpload4] => sandisk-ultra-dual-drive-sddd3-016g-i35-original-imaenuzggxzwqcfh.jpeg
    [fileToUpload5] => stock-vector-white-textile-banners-vector-template-ready-for-your-text-and-design-153620174.jpg
)

Comment: i want all images descriptions

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following two methods.

1. Use **GET** method to get all the form data, Like this

   `<form action="<?php echo $baseurl.'admin/AdminSample/sampleOne';?>" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
2. Or Please go through this link
   https://www.softprodigy.com/store/article/how-to-upload-multiple-iimage-in-admin-backend-in-magento2/

you will get an suitable answer